# Wicket: update model via TextFields in a ListView

Tags: java, wicket

I am coding a simple panel that renders uploaded images and their alt texts using `ListView`. I am able to show the uploaded images and also their alt texts from database, but I can't find the solution to update alt texts via `TextFields`.

Here's the model for presenting data, works as expected:

```
this.listModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<Object>() {
    protected Object load() {
    ArrayList<SingleImage> images = SingleImageDao.getImagesByPageId(pageId);
    return images;
    }
};
```

And here's the `setListView()` method:

```
this.setListView(new ListView("imageListItem", this.listModel) {
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem item) {
    final SingleImage singleImage = (SingleImage) item.getModelObject();

    item.add(new AttributeModifier("id", singleImage.getId()));
    item.add(new Image("imageListItemImg",
        new ContextRelativeResource(uploadedImgDir
            + singleImage.getFileName())));

    final TextField altText = new TextField<String>("altText", new PropertyModel<String>(singleImage, "altText"));
    item.add(altText);
    }
});
this.listView.setReuseItems(true);
```

There's also a button that should save the changes:

```
this.saveButton = new AjaxButton("saveButton") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
    target.add(listContainer);
    }
};
```

`listContainer` is a `WebMarkupContainer` that wraps the `ListView`. Any ideas how to update the `altText` fields?

**EDIT:** Tom asked for complete Java class and HTML page.

Java class:

```
public class ImageListPanel extends Panel {
    private final String uploadedImgDir = "img//uploaded//";
    private int pageId;
    private IModel<?> listModel = null;
    private ListView<?> listView = null;
    private WebMarkupContainer imageListContainer = null;
    private WebMarkupContainer listContainer = null;
    private Form<?> actionButtons = null;
    private AjaxButton saveButton = null;

    public ImageListPanel(String id, final int pageId) {
        super(id);
        this.pageId = pageId;

        this.listModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<Object>() {
            protected Object load() {
                ArrayList<SingleImage> images = SingleImageDao.getImagesByPageId(pageId);
                return images;
            }
        };

        this.setListView(new ListView("imageListItem", this.listModel) {
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem item) {
                final SingleImage singleImage = (SingleImage) item.getModelObject();

                item.add(new AttributeModifier("id", singleImage.getId()));
                item.add(new Image("imageListItemImg",
                    new ContextRelativeResource(uploadedImgDir
                        + singleImage.getFileName())));
                final TextField altText = new TextField<String>("altText", new PropertyModel<String>(singleImage, "altText"));
                item.add(altText);
            }
        });

        this.listView.setReuseItems(true);

        this.imageListContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("imageListContainer");
        this.listContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("listContainer");
        this.setActionButtons(new Form<Void>("actionButtons"));
        this.saveButton = new AjaxButton("saveButton") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
                target.add(listContainer);
                listContainer.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "passive"));
            }
        };
        this.imageListContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.listContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(this.imageListContainer);
        this.imageListContainer.add(this.listContainer);
        this.listContainer.add(this.listView);
        this.listView.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.getActionButtons().setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.getActionButtons().add(this.saveButton);
        this.imageListContainer.add(this.getActionButtons());
    }

    public int getPageId() {
        return pageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(int pageId) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }

    public WebMarkupContainer getListContainer() {
        return listContainer;
    }

    public void setListContainer(WebMarkupContainer listContainer) {
        this.listContainer = listContainer;
    }

    public ListView<?> getListView() {
        return listView;
    }

    public void setListView(ListView<?> listView) {
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    public Form<?> getActionButtons() {
        return actionButtons;
    }

    public void setActionButtons(Form<?> actionButtons) {
        this.actionButtons = actionButtons;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.3-strict.dtd"
    xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="imageListContainer" id="image-list-container">
            <div wicket:id="listContainer" id="imagesContainer">
                <ul id="sortable">
                    <li wicket:id="imageListItem" class="img-list-item">
                        <img wicket:id="imageListItemImg" class="thumbnail" />
                        <input wicket:id="altText" class="altText" type="text" size="40" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form wicket:id="actionButtons">
                <p>
                    <input wicket:id="saveButton" id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:** updated code, the ListView is now wrapped inside a Form.

Java class:

```
public class ImageListPanel extends Panel {
private final String uploadedImgDir = "img//uploaded//";
private int pageId;
private IModel<?> listModel = null;
private ListView<?> listView = null;
private WebMarkupContainer imageListContainer = null;
private WebMarkupContainer listContainer = null;

public ImageListPanel(String id, final int pageId) {
    super(id);
    this.pageId = pageId;

    this.listModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<Object>() {
        protected Object load() {
            ArrayList<SingleImage> images = SingleImageDao.getImagesByPageId(pageId);
            return images;
        }
    };

    this.setListView(new ListView("imageListItem", this.listModel) {
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem item) {
            final SingleImage singleImage = (SingleImage) item.getModelObject();

            item.add(new AttributeModifier("id", singleImage.getId()));
            item.add(new Image("imageListItemImg",
                new ContextRelativeResource(uploadedImgDir
                    + singleImage.getFileName())));
            final TextField altText = new TextField<String>("altText", new PropertyModel<String>(singleImage, "altText"));
            item.add(altText);
        }
    });

    this.listView.setReuseItems(true);
    Form formListView = new Form("formListView", this.listModel) {
        protected void onSubmit() {
            ArrayList<SingleImage> images = (ArrayList<SingleImage>) listModel.getObject();
            for (SingleImage singleImage : images) {
                System.out.println(singleImage.getAltText());
            }
        };
    };



    this.imageListContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("imageListContainer");
    this.listContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("listContainer");
    this.imageListContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    this.listContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(this.imageListContainer);
    this.imageListContainer.add(this.listContainer);
    //this.listContainer.add(this.listView);
    this.listContainer.add(formListView);
    formListView.add(this.listView);
    this.listView.setOutputMarkupId(true);
}

public int getPageId() {
    return pageId;
}

public void setPageId(int pageId) {
    this.pageId = pageId;
}

public WebMarkupContainer getListContainer() {
    return listContainer;
}

public void setListContainer(WebMarkupContainer listContainer) {
    this.listContainer = listContainer;
}

public ListView<?> getListView() {
    return listView;
}

public void setListView(ListView<?> listView) {
    this.listView = listView;
}
```

}

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.3-strict.dtd"
    xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="imageListContainer" id="image-list-container">
            <div wicket:id="listContainer" id="imagesContainer">

                <form wicket:id="formListView">
                    <ul id="sortable">
                        <li wicket:id="imageListItem" class="img-list-item">
                            <img wicket:id="imageListItemImg" class="thumbnail" />
                            <input wicket:id="altText" class="altText" type="text" size="40" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a Wicket Form component around the Listview and AjaxButton? Please post the complete Java and HTML code of your page.

Comment: There is a Form component around the AjaxButton, but not the ListView. I edited my post and included complete source code.

Comment: You are discarding user input do to the use of a LDM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display a list of images each with a text field to edit its alt-text and store it in the database. In the code you posted you have to change the following:

- surround the whole list with the form. Currently, the input field is not part of the form and thus the user input cannot be posted to the server-side Wicket code. In your setup, the whole listview will be added of the form then instead of the parent panel.
- implement form.onSubmit(). In the onSubmit()-method you can access the value of the input textfield via singleImage.getAltText() and store in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Tom. I did the following: I added a Form to listContainer and added a ListView to a Form. I implemented the onSubmit method and tested the functionality by outputting the altTexts. Still, the model wasnt't updated, I get the same old values. `Form formListView = new Form("formListView", this.listModel){`
    `protected void onSubmit() {`
 `ArrayList<SingleImage> images = (ArrayList<SingleImage>) listModel.getObject();`
  `for (SingleImage singleImage : images){`
   `System.out.println(singleImage.getAltText());`
  `}`
        `};`
 `};`

Comment: Try using a default submit button instead of the AjaxButton. Remove the AjaxButton and just put an "<input type="submit"/>" into the HTML. This submit button doesn't need be added to the form in the Java code.

Comment: That's strange. Actually I already did what you just said. I removed the AjaxButton and added "<input type="submit"/>" after a "</form>" in HTML. I didn't declared the new "submit" button in Java code, just overrided the onSubmit method inside a form.

Comment: Try using a different Model than LoadableDetachableModel. I guess the LoadableDetachableModel reloads the data from the database so the input from the textfield never reaches the model.

Comment: OK, it's clear now: surrounding list with the form and overriding onSubmit() works if submit button is placed inside <form> tag in html file. Thanks, Tom